# Can DirectX 3D Meshes be merged, or joined together

Tags: c#, directx

C# programmer, beginner DirectX.
Have created 2 meshes using Mesh.Cylinder but need to combine them into a single mesh. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah thats doable.  You have a transform matrix for both meshes presumably?

Lock both meshes and then take the 1st mesh (I will assume we add it to the second) and transform its vertices one by one by the matrix transformation transfoming from cylinder 1s local space to clyinder 2's local space (ie [cylinder 1 world transform] * [inverse cylinder 2 world transform]).   Define up the correct indices and you have now added mesh 1 to Mesh 2.

It will get more compilcated if you want both meshes to intersect properly.  If you want to do that I suggest you look into Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG).  There are plenty of links to be found on google on the subject.

Comment: I have found DirectX Mesh has a static `concatenate` method,what does that method used for？

Comment: @zionpi: It doesn't appear to perform CSG but should combine the 2 meshes, sure.

Comment: Weird enough,I try to `concatenate` two user defined mesh,only  one of them showed up.Besides,CSG seems only perform on *primitive* shapes like cylinder,cone,cube,I do not know if it is true.Or does the mesh requires *special* format?

Comment: @zionpi: I guess it depends on how you set your matrices.  Why not start a question about it and include some code (like how you call concatenate and how you normally render)?